# Iterating over Dataframes - revisited?

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, nested-loops

I have a dataframe of about 500.000 rows. Contains long, lat,, altitude, datetime (and a LOT more data) of aircraft radar data.

To calculate 'propensity' (a dimensionsless number based on closest point of approach [cpa] theory) I do the following:

1. take a chunk of rows within a certain time window (currently 3 seconds, holds about 20-40 rows of data. This is simply based on selecting a group of rows based on 'datetime. Then calling a function that operates on this chunk.

```
    timeslice_start = row[1]['df']['datetime'].iloc[0]
    timeslice_end = timeslice_start + timeslice

    # while the end of the timeslice has not reached the end of the dataframe:
    while timeslice_end <= row[1]['df']['datetime'].iloc[-1]:
        # Take a group of datapoints that are in the timeslice
        this_group = row[1]['df'][(row[1]['df']['datetime'] >= timeslice_start) & (row[1]['df']['datetime'] <= timeslice_end)]

        do_checks3D(this_group, row[1]['limits'][0], row[1]['limits'][1], row[1]['limits'][2])
```

This is a sliding window technique. Recently I discovered that pandas actually has a function for this with pandas.rolling(), but have not tried that yet as I do not expect a big performance boost.

2. This group of data is then passed to a function to calculate cpa of all aircraft points in that chunk of data by iterating over the rows using a 'for' loop with a nested 'for' loop as follows:

```
for i in range(0, len(dframe)):
        # extracting parameters for vector1 of aircraft 1
        
        # and compare it with all the other datapoints in the frame
        for j in range(i+1,len(dframe)):
            # do more extraction for vector2 of aircraft 2
            # and call the cpa function
            cpa(vector1, vector2)
```

Effectively, this gives me the same as pandas.combinations(). However, using combinations() is much slower than brute force iterating like I do now.

3. Slide window forward (currently 1 sec) and call the function again. Obviously this will give many overlaps which need to be weeded out later.

Calculating all cpas for a day's worth of datapoints, will cost me around 30 minutes on a normal PC. I am looking for ways to significantly speed up the code.
Would you have any suggestions?
Is pandas.rolling() faster than my sliding window? Is there a better Pythonic way?
Is there a faster way than my two nested 'for' loops?

Any suggestions very welcome!

Comment: Kindly add simple small  input and output dataframes

Comment: Input dataframe is big and remains unaltered. Contains data of each radar point.
Output dataframe contains datetime, first aircraft data, second aircraft data, and details about the closest point of approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.rolling()` will almost certainly be faster - the data will be processed by the C core instead of by Python. You could combine this with [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) to apply a custom function to each frame of the window.

However, using `.apply()` with a python function will mean that the data will probably be processed by Python instead of by pandas, which is slower (but still faster than a for loop). It may be possible to rewrite your code to prevent this, but that may not be necessary: I'd use `.apply()` first and see if it's still too slow.

Comment: Thanks. I think the majority of computing is spend in the nested ```for``` loops so that is where I would first look. It is difficult for me to see how I can use ```.apply()``` on a group of rows.

Comment: @JobBrüggen If you set the datetime as the index, you can use rolling to create the groups by time, e.g. `df.rolling('3s').apply` - although depending on what `do_checks3D()` and `cpa()` actually do - there may be a way to do it using `.agg` instead - perhaps you can show a minimal example.

Comment: Yes, df.rolling() is probably useable. I do still need a simple numeric index for later comparisons, perhaps I can set datetime as index and later return to numeric. And as said, I think that is not where the majority of computing time is spend. I will study ```.agg()``` some more to see if that could help.

Comment: ```.agg()``` looks like this is not going to help much. It is a function for every row. What I am doing is comparing all combinations of rows against each other.

Comment: fwiw I'm working on almost this exact issue, but the dataset is almost a billion rows long, so I ended up falling back to writing in C. 30 minutes is honestly not a huge amount in the scheme of things, so if it's still slow after using `.rolling.apply()`, I'd just make a script to set it running at the start/ end of the day.

Comment: Hey thanks! Exactly what I did of course; daily processing, automated to start every morning at 07:00. Thirty minutes for a day is totally acceptable. I ran the script every day for the whole of 2022. However, the propensity calculation has been refined and updated and I want to re-run the entire year 2022. Now it is getting to more than a week of processing... haha.

Comment: @JobBrüggen There may be pandas functionality you can use instead of the current double for loop approach - this is why people are asking for an actual example of what you're doing. If you cannot use `.agg` - then you could parallelize the `.apply` e.g. using `joblib` (this is one reason why using `.rolling` to generate groups would be beneficial)

Comment: Okay, I will try to assemble an example. Let me work on that for a while. (And I have never heard of ```joblib```...)